How to select the image size in "Image3DSlices"?
I want to get 100 images of 100x100 size 2D image data with "Image3DSlices" command.
randomSpheres = Table[{Sphere[RandomReal[{0, 150}, 3], RandomReal[{1, 10}]]}, {20}]
g3 = Graphics3D[randomSpheres]  (*... eq2*)
si2 = RegionImage[DiscretizeGraphics[g3]];
si3 = si2 // FillingTransform // Binarize;
slice = Image3DSlices[si3]  

However, I cannot set the size of each image of slice... The size seems to be the value of "PlotRange->All", everytime differnet size because the spheres radius and center coodinate are random. I want to make Dimensions of each image of "slice" to be 100x100, as
Dimensions[ImageData[slice[[i]]]] = {100, 100}

for i th image.
Besides, the number of "slice" also seems to depend on the "PlotRange->All" of z direction. I want the number of 2D pictures(="slice") to be 100, but
Dimensions[slice] 

differs everytime...
If someone who knows how to get the cubic data, please tell me.
I tried to change eq2 as
g3 = Graphics3D[randomSpheres, PlotRange -> {{0, 100}, {0, 100}, {0, 100}}]

However, the dimensions of each "slice" image was not 100x100 still. Moreover, some of the spheres were not fully filled... In desired images, all spheres should be filled.

To make the slices 100 x 100, Maybe try slice = ImageResize[#, {100, 100}] & /@ slice; ? Leaving this as a comment because it doesn't answer the other parts of the question

One way to get 100 slices of 100x100 size, given s random spheres:
SeedRandom[123456];
n = 150; r = 10; s = 20;
spheres = Table[Sphere[RandomReal[{0, n}, 3], RandomReal[{1, r}]], {s}];
mesh = 
  DiscretizeGraphics[Graphics3D@spheres, MaxCellMeasure -> 1, PerformanceGoal -> "Speed"];
bounds = Table[{-r, n + r}, {3}]; size = 100;
img = RegionImage[mesh, bounds, RasterSize -> size]


fimg = img // FillingTransform // Binarize;
ImageDimensions@fimg


{100, 100, 100}

slices = Image3DSlices[fimg];
ImageDimensions /@ slices // Tally


{{{100, 100}, 100}}

Multicolumn[RandomChoice[slices, 9], 3]





Alternatively, Ball can be used instead of Sphere in order to avoid the FillingTransform operation.
SeedRandom[123];
n = 150; r = 10; s = 20;
balls = Table[Ball[RandomReal[{0, n}, 3], RandomReal[{1, r}]], {s}];
mesh = DiscretizeRegion[RegionUnion@balls, MaxCellMeasure -> 1, 
   PerformanceGoal -> "Speed"];

bounds = Table[{0, n}, {3}]; size = 100;
img = RegionImage[mesh, bounds, RasterSize -> size]


slices = Image3DSlices[Binarize@img];
Multicolumn[RandomChoice[slices, 9], 3]


ImageDimensions /@ slices // Tally


{{{100, 100}, 100}}


Thank you so much! Your answer is very useful. Thanks again!!
